# Can't access parent view controller's variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I am trying apply a basic inheritance concept, I need to display parent viewcontorller's `textfield.text`'s in child view controller. But I am getting null values

Parent.h

```
@interface EditEventViewController : UITableViewController
{
 UITextField *textEventName;
    UITextField *textEventLocation;
    UITextField *textStartTime;
    UITextField *textEndTime;
    UITextField *textDate;
    UITextField *textEndDate;

    //tried IBOutlet version  such as
    //IBOutlet UITextField *textEventName;//this didnt work too
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textEventName;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textEventLocation;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textStartTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textEndTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textDate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITextField *textEndDate;
```

Parent.m

```
  @synthesize textEndDate=_textEndDate;
@synthesize textDate=_textDate;
@synthesize textEndTime=_textEndTime;
@synthesize textEventName=_textEventName;
@synthesize textStartTime=_textStartTime;
@synthesize textEventLocation=_textEventLocation;

//test inherritance here
     DeleteFromCalendar *deleteControl=[[DeleteFromCalendar alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Delete Request for text name %@",self.textEventName.text);
    [deleteControl displayParentStrings];
```

Child.h

```
#import "EditEventViewController.h"

@interface DeleteFromCalendar : EditEventViewController

-(void)displayParentStrings;

@end
```

Child.m

```
-(void)displayParentStrings
{
    NSLog(@"Display Parent Strings");
    NSLog(@"DeleteFromCalendar Event Name %@",textEventName.text);
    NSLog(@"DeleteFromCalendar  Event  %@",textEventLocation.text);
}
```

NSLOG:

```
Delete Request for text name Aeronautical Knowledge Review
DeleteFromCalendar Event Name (null)
DeleteFromCalendar  Event Lcoation (null)
```

Why do I get null?

Comment: Have you hooked the UI elements up to their outlets in interface builder?  Also, you shouldn't need to synthesize the properties in the child if they were declared in the parent.  (And in Xcode 4 you don't need to synthesize properties anyway--this is now automatic.)

Comment: Do not declare again the properties in the child.m it will override the parent ones. Also don't declare a variable as property and class member, use only one of these. ;). Also you don't need to declare the method in the child.h file, it is already declared in the parrent.

Comment: Sorry copy paste error , didnt re-declare textfields in child

Comment: @NicholasHart yes , I have hooked text fields in IB , as you can see `NSLog(@"Delete Request for text name %@",self.textEventName.text);` prints `Delete Request for text name Aeronautical Knowledge Review` in parent view before I call child vc

Comment: That log message didn't come from `-displayParentStrings` as you've shown it to us; if it did, it'd start with "Display Parent Strings". How about showing us the real code?

Comment: @Caleb It did, I just forgot to copy paste that line from xcode log

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're using `self.textEventName.text` to access the `textEventName` property in Parent.m, but you're only using `textEventName.text` in Child.m. That's meaningless -- it's the equivalent of this:

```
[[  textEventName] text];   // Error: you're not specifying the receiver of the message
```

If you want to access a property of an object, you need to specify *which* object. In this case, that object is `self`.

Change the code in `-displayParentStrings` thus:

```
NSLog(@"DeleteFromCalendar Event Name %@", self.textEventName.text);
NSLog(@"DeleteFromCalendar  Event  %@", self.textEventLocation.text);
```

Adding `self.` will solve your problem.

Comment: I already tried that before posting the question , didnt work thats why I asked the question.

Comment: My answer and Ahmed's point out some major flaws in your code, but perhaps there are others. Why not correct the things we've shown you by replacing your code with Ahmed's, and then edit your question to include more information if you still can't get it working?

Answer (score 0):

Caleb's answer will solve the problem but that's not all. The real problem is that you synthesized the properties with the underscore prefixes. So when you are doing `textEventName.text`, you are accessing the instance variables you declared in Parent.h NOT the variables synthesized with the properties. But interface builder is hooked to assign the UI elements to the properties. So they are assigned to those with the underscore prefixes. Therefore, the instance variables without the underscores are nil. You should therefore, change you code as follows.

Parent.h

```
@interface EditEventViewController : UITableViewController

// you don't need the instance variables

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *textEventName;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *textEventLocation;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *textStartTime;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *textEndTime;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *textDate;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *textEndDate;
```

Parent.m

```
// you don't need to synthesize

//test inherritance here
    DeleteFromCalendar *deleteControl=[[DeleteFromCalendar alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"Delete Request for text name %@",self.textEventName.text);
    [deleteControl displayParentStrings];
```

Child.h

```
#import "EditEventViewController.h"

@interface DeleteFromCalendar : EditEventViewController

-(void)displayParentStrings;

@end
```

Child.m

```
-(void)displayParentStrings
{
    NSLog(@"Display Parent Strings");
    NSLog(@"DeleteFromCalendar Event Name %@", self.textEventName.text);
    NSLog(@"DeleteFromCalendar  Event  %@", self.textEventLocation.text);
}
```

or

```
-(void)displayParentStrings
{
    NSLog(@"Display Parent Strings");
    NSLog(@"DeleteFromCalendar Event Name %@", _textEventName.text);
    NSLog(@"DeleteFromCalendar  Event  %@", _textEventLocation.text);
}
```

Comment: *accessing the instance variables you declared in Parent.h* Good catch -- that explains why the compiler doesn't complain. I'd remove the second version of `-displayParentStrings` -- it's better to use the property accessors in the subclass than to use the ivars directly.

Comment: @Caleb I agree it is better to use the properties. I just included that for completeness

Answer (score 0):

You mistook the subclass concept (inheritance concept) vs instance of a class.  They are completely not related.  When you subclass a class, you create a new class that inherits those (some ?) properties associated with that class.  The keyword here is that you just created a new class.  Any objects can create an instance of this subclass.... not just the parent of this subclass.

The concept is very much spplying to all object oriented programming languages.  Search the web for "subclass vs instance", you should be able to see more discussion on this topic.  Good luck!